# Rank mismatch in argument error in Fortran 77 not being reported

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran, fortran90, fortran77

I am trying to port a piece of code from Fortran 77 to Fortran 90 and I had a question regarding catching rank mismatch in argument in Fortran 77.

This is the code in Fortran 90

```
program test 
use my_module
real         ml_time
call gettimes(cdfid,ml_time,ml_ntimes)
```

In the calling subroutine this is how the passed variable is defined

```
module my_module 
use netcdf

subroutine gettimes(cdfid,times,ntimes)
real times(*)

  call check(nf90_inq_dimid(cdfid,'time', timid))

  call check(nf90_inquire_dimension(cdfid, timid, len = ntimes))

  call check(nf90_inq_varid(cdfid,'time',timid))

  call check(nf90_get_var(cdfid,timid,times(1:ntimes)))


end subroutine gettimes
```

In Fortran 77 (.f file) and gfortran 5.4 why does this not produce a compile error?

The same code when I ported it to Fortran 90 produces a rank mismatch compile error.

This is the error in Fortran 90

```
add2p.f90:191:22:

call gettimes(cdfid,ml_time,ml_ntimes)
                  1
Error: Rank mismatch in argument ‘times’ at (1) (rank-1 and scalar)
```

In Fortran 77 this is how the code is organized

```
program test 
real         ml_time
call gettimes(cdfid,ml_time,ml_ntimes)
```

In another file xyz.f

```
  subroutine gettimes(cdfid,times,ntimes,ierr)

  include "netcdf.inc"

  integer   ierr,i
  real times(*)
  integer didtim,ntimes

  integer   cdfid,idtime


  do 10 i=1,ntimes
    call ncvgt1(cdfid,idtime,i,times(i)) ! get times
  10 continue




  end
```

Of course I got rid of the error by making them the same rank but I was wondering why the compiler error is not reported in Fortran 77.

Comment: Please show the error that is generated in Fortran 90 and some reasonably *complete* code example [mcve].

Comment: The whole structure is needed, not just the subroutine, see my answer why.

Comment: @VladimirF - have the changes i made acceptable ?

Comment: Yes, I think it is fine for this case.

Comment: @VladimirF - I added the F77 code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not show enough code to be sure, but you are likely using explicit interfaces (e.g., modules) in your Fortran 90 code. In that case the compiler is obliged to check for this inconsistency and must produce an error. That is not the case when implicit interfaces are used (they were no explicit interfaces in Fortran 77).

It is allowed to pass a scalar to an assumed size array only if the scalar is an array element (see *sequence association*).

I do get a warning in gfortran 4.8, but that may not happen if the call is in a different source file:

```
  subroutine s1(a)
    integer :: a(*)
  end

  subroutine s2()
    call s1(1)
  end subroutine

> gfortran rank.f90 -c
rank.f90:7.12:

    call s1(1)
            1
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument 'a' at (1) (rank-1 and scalar)
```

Note that compiler compiles every source code as Fortran 2008 + extensions by default. It does not distinguish between Fortran 90 and 77 in any way.

Notably, .f and .f90 does NOT mean Fortran 77 and Fortran 90, they mean fixed form and free form source. Both of these source forms are valid Fortran 90 - Fortran 2008.

Comment: so in Fortran 77 how does the scalar get converted into a vector or vice versa or is that a separate question ? :)

Comment: There is no conversion, it is accessed as a length 1 array using the pointer (call by reference) and it works because a scalar and length 1 array are represented the same in memory. See questions and asnwers about sequence association.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/03/31/doctor-fortran-in-ive-come-here-for-an-argument. "Sequence Association" Thanks for pointing out the concept

Comment: Indeed, that article is very good. Note especially *"You'll also get this error (as error #8299) if you are passing a scalar that isn't an array element, such as a constant 1 or a scalar variable, to an array dummy argument.  In some cases you can use an array constructor to turn the scalar into an array, such as [1], but you will lose sequence association benefits."*